# Android Kotlin static map not being loaded by glide. and map marker not visible

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-glide

I am using google maps static image api to load a map inside an image view. My code is as given below. The generated URL is showing image when opened in browser but the marker is not shown. Even though the url is correct the image is not visible in the app.

generated url: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=51.35052,-0.149648&zoom=10&size=200x200&sensor=false&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:C%51.35052,-0.149648&key=API_KEY

```
var url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" +
                    restaurant.latitude +
                    "," +
                    restaurant.longitude +
                    "&zoom=10&size=200x200&sensor=false" +
                    "&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:C%" +
                    restaurant.latitude +
                    "," +
                    restaurant.longitude +
                    "&key=API_KEY"

            Log.e("url", url)
            Glide
                .with(context)
                .load(url)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(holder.map)
```

image

[image]

Comment: As to how the Android Studio does not load the static map, I do not know, but the reason why your marker does not show is because after the `label:C` you only had `%` instead of `%7C`.

Comment: `"&key=API_KEY"` this actually needs to contain your apikey and not the word API_KEY

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I cannot validate a link as there is no `API_KEY`. Can you, please, also upload a static image from the url?

Anyway, assuming the link is correct I still have no idea how it supposed work. For example, you did not specify and coordinates or similar. At the same time I believe there is [no API](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/400/com/bumptech/glide/RequestBuilder.html) that will load image through the Glide `into` a view or specifically `mapView`.

Instead of doing direct loading, I would load `into` [a custom target](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/targets.html#specifying-targets). Use `CustomTarget` the doc is a bit outdated.

```java
Glide.with(this)
        .asBitmap()
        .load(imagePath)
        .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>(){
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Bitmap, transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                // load your resource into mapView
            }

            override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                // handle errors
            }
        })
```

And then add a `Marker` to the `map` with your bitmap resource

```kotlin
googleMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
            .position(...)
            .title(...)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resource)))
```